# Режим MySQL "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION", что это такое?

Tags: mysql

Что значит режим MySQL `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`?

В [официальной доке](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution) сказано:

> Control automatic substitution of the default storage engine when a statement such as `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` specifies a storage engine that is disabled or not compiled in.
>
> By default, `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` is enabled.
>
> Because storage engines can be pluggable at runtime, unavailable engines are treated the same way:
>
> With `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` disabled, for `CREATE TABLE` the default engine is used and a warning occurs if the desired engine is unavailable. For `ALTER TABLE`, a warning occurs and the table is not altered.
>
> With `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` enabled, an error occurs and the table is not created or altered if the desired engine is unavailable.

Но мне так и не стало ясно что это и для чего.

Объясните, кто действительно знает, простым и понятным языком предназначение этого режима, можно с примерами. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Представьте, что вы делаете некую операцию, влияющую на тип таблицы (движок, механизм хранения, ENGINE), устанавливая его при `CREATE TABLE` или изменяя при `ALTER TABLE`.

Возможны варианты:

1. В запросе не указан тип таблицы - будет использован тип таблиц по умолчанию.
2. В запросе указан тип таблицы, и он доступен - будет использоваться указанный тип.
3. В запросе указан тип таблицы, но он недоступен (отключен или не скомпилирован) и `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` **отключен** - будет использован тип таблиц по умолчанию (для `CREATE TABLE`) либо запрос не будет выполнен (для `ALTER TABLE`), но в любом случае ошибки не возникнет (зато будет выдано предупреждение).
4. В запросе указан тип таблицы, но он недоступен (отключен или не скомпилирован) и `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` **включен** - операция не будет выполнена, будет выдано сообщение об ошибке.

P.S. Отключенный/недоступный тип таблиц нельзя сделать дефолтным. Дефолтный тип таблиц нельзя отключить.